# When using grep the message "Binary file (standard input) matches" appears

Tags: bash, grep

I was using a temporal file to find all the files that use a certain extension and after executing all the files I wanted appeared, but with the message Binary file (standard input) matches. What should I do to fix it when $i is the directory that is inspected and $1 the extension?

```
tempfile=$(mktemp)
ls "$i" | grep -v -e '^total` -e *.$1 > $tempfile
cat $tempfile

Coincidencia en el archivo binario Ejercicio bases practica.odb
Coincidencia en el archivo binario Ejercicio PR4.odb
```

I also tried other ways to delete all the other lines from the temporaly file and this one was the only one that seemed, or was close being correct. I tried to use -a as many other cases recomended but it didn't work.

Comment: Files with extension _.odb_ are binary files, not text files. They are archives of XML and other files like images, for instance. That's why I guess `grep` is telling you that these are binary files.

Comment: Make sure to copy your exact code when presenting a problem, as what you currently have has at least two unrelated errors (blanks around `=`, `<` instead of `>`).

Comment: The reason for the message is that some non-text bytes were part of the `ls "$i"` output. These might be control characters or other characters not part of the current locale. Could you post the result of `locale` and `ls "$i"` verbatim?

Comment: [Don't try to parse the output of ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: I don't know what you are exactly doing here. You can of course provide the `-a` option for grep, so that it treats every input as text file. The real interesting question is, why `grep` classifies the stdout of `ls` as binary. While EdMorton is surely right that you shouldn't do this, I would conclude from this that your directory contains plenty of files which contain unprintable or otherwise funny  characters. What do you see when you do a `ls "$i" | tee /tmp/x | grep ...` and then look at `/tmp/x` using a hex dump?

Comment: @afarrag : The `grep` in the posting does **not** search an odb file, so this can't be the reason, if this is **really** the original code used by the OP.

Comment: Not really related to your problem, but: `dir1` is a poorly choosen variable name, given that the variable holds the name of a file, not a directory.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your typo:

```
ls "$i" | grep -v -e '^total` -e *.$1 > $tempfile
                    ^^^    ^^^  ^^^
```

Were you searching for `'^total'` and `*.$1`?

```bash
ls "$i" | grep -v -e '^total' -e ".*\.$1" > $tempfile
```

Or were you searching fo `` '^total` -e *.$1' ``?

```bash
ls "$i" | grep -v -e "^total` -e *.$1" > $tempfile
```

Your quotes are not balanced and it's not clear if you are trying to use a position variable or trully dollar-one extension.

Comment: Good point. In this case, the outcome depends of course on the value of the first parameter of the script as well, and on the files in the working directory, which match `*.$1`. Actually, if there is more than one matching file, an error message would occur.  @Acemamo: To match lines which have the value of `$1` after a literal period, the pattern has to be something like `-e "[.]$1"`.

Answer (score 0):

To list all files in Bash you can use `find` command for example `find . -name \*.txt -print` to list all files with `.txt` extension. It will search just using filename (not content).